# Ghostscript PDF Writer supersizing individual characters on processing

Tags: macos, pdf, ghostscript

When processing an input PDF using the Roboto font embedded into the PDF, Ghostscript PDF Writer increases the size of each individual character on the page making it illegible on MacOS Preview.

I've not been able to duplicate this on all Macs, and it primarily happens in Apple's Preview app (doesn't happen in Adobe Acrobat or Chrome's PDF viewer). When printing to some printers, such as Canon's, the driver will oftentimes produce the same garbled text - again, still only from MacOS.

Terminal execution: `gs '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite' '-o./output.pdf' 'input.pdf'`

Possibly pertinent information:

- MacOS Version: 10.14.6
- GhostScript Version: Both 9.52 and 9.55
- MacOS Preview Version: 10.1 (944.6.16.1)

**Input** [input.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nzk1newFxKAL2g2HCF2WhgJ4mFgKzYVK/view?usp=sharing):
[image: Input Image]

**Output** [output.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p8841_H14VJ1BOme8AOBxfNAYptkP3D9/view?usp=sharing)
[image: Output image]

Some other possibly useful information about things I've tried w/ Ghostscript options, and every combination of them:

- Subsetting fonts doesn't work
- Embedding fonts doesn't work
- PDF compatibility mode changes don't work

The only way I've been able to get past this issue is to rasterize and convert the entire PDF to an image, which doesn't work for my use case because the PDF then cannot be searched, the file is larger, the print quality is raster and pixelated (we're essentially printing an image, so that all makes sense)

Comment: Are you saying that the same PDF file behaves differently when viewed in Acrobat and when viewed using Apple Preview ? Because that sounds to me very much like a bug in Apple Preview to me. FWIW taking your input file works for me here, and I see nothing suspicious in the output PDF file. Since you already have a PDF file, what is the point in making a new one ?

Comment: @KenS I would agree with the conclusion regarding Apple Preview, except it doesn't occur with any other PDF files. In terms of processing through Ghostscript, there's a lot of reasons we're doing that. Ghostscript changes the compatibility version for us, remove embedded form fields, allows us to split out the PDF, etc. so it's necessary for us to run all of our PDFs through GS. This is one example of the issue, but it happens on a series of other PDF documents and we can't control the input.

Comment: Well I can see that there is a problem with Mac Preview (even with a simplified file). There is nothing in the output file that looks suspicious though. If I had to guess I would suspect the fact the content is buried inside two nested forms. These appear to be due to editing with TCPDF which seems to invisibly stamp the output, and put the preceding content in a form. The only real difference in the content is that the original scales the font using the text matrix, but leaves the font size at 1, whereas the GS output sets the font size to 'x' and leaves the text matrix at the identity.